# UFT Test detection service jenkins ¿Does this service generate ATs for me in Octane?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hp-uft, uft14

When the job reaches that part is the AT generated in Octane automatically?

[image]

How can I locate them? I'm trying to add them to a TS

Thanks for the help

Comment: When generating the test runner, it generates two jobs: Discovery and test runer. The discovery uploads the AT entities and the test runner runs the tests from octane